# Medical Image processing, taking special pattern part and attaching on another image

Tags: image-processing, medical

[image]

Like the picture above, I want to take the image pattern of the part of the box or mask and paste it into another medical image, is there a way?

Comment: the answer is **yes**.

Comment: Please read [tour] and [ask]. Then search for [tag:opencv].

Comment: See *"Image ROI"* here https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html